# rails update_attributes don't update value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes, attr-accessible

When trying to update the value **read_at** from Message model it don't have any kind of effect using the **update_attributes** function.

Here is the Message table

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.integer :sender_id, null: false
      t.integer :receiver_id
      t.string :subject
      t.text :body
      t.datetime :read_at
      t.string :container, default: "draft"
      t.boolean :sender_deleted, default: false
      t.boolean :receiver_deleted, default: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end    
  def down
    drop_table :messages
  end
end
```

Here is Message Model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible   :subject, :body, :container, :sender_id, :receiver_id, :read_at

  belongs_to :sender,
        class_name: 'User'

  belongs_to :receiver,
        class_name: 'User'
```

Here is User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :messages_sent,
    class_name: 'Message',
    foreign_key: 'sender_id',
    dependent: :destroy    

has_many :messages_received,
    class_name: 'Message',
    foreign_key: 'receiver_id',
    dependent: :destroy
```

Then at the terminal

```
user1 = User.create(name: "user1_name", email: "user1@email.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
user2 = User.create(name: "user2_name", email: "user2@email.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")

msg1 = Message.create(sender_id: user1.id, receiver_id: user2.id, subject: 'subject_msg1', body: 'body_msg1')
msg1.save

@m = Message.find(msg1.id)
@m.update_attributes(read_at: Time.now)
```

I get this outputs:

```
@m.read_at
=>datestamped

msg1.read_at
=>nil
```

For sure I'm missing something here, but I can't see where it is after changing and rechanging the **has_many** and the **belongs_to** from the associations, because I did put the **read_at** over the **attr_accessible** list
HELP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `msg1.reload` before `msg1.read_at`

or

```
msg1.reload.read_at
```

Comment: Despite **@m** and **msg1** having the same **id**, using the `@m.update_attributes(read_at: Time.now)` will update the **read_at** attribute from **@m** only. After executing `msg1.reload` it will update the **msg1.read_at** value. I don't understand why? Over my Message model making a function to update the attr it doesn't works if I don't use **reload** at the message it self. Can you explain why? I does work over others attr, only at this one it don't update it self

Answer (score 1):

In order to update values, you should use

```
@m.update_attributes(:read_at => Time.now)
```

Refer [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) for further details

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the documentation.

Use attr_accessible to prevent mass assignment (by users) of attributes that should not be editable by a user. Mass assignment is used in create and update methods of your standard controller.

For a normal user account, for example, you only want login and password to be editable by a user. It should not be possible to change the status attribute through mass assignment.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  attr_accessible :login, :password
end
```

So, doing the following will merrily return true, but will not update the status attribute.

```
@user.update_attributes(:status => 'active')
```

If you want to update the status attribute, you should assign it separately.

```
@user.status = 'active'
save
```

or just use update_attribute